# How to add GPInMemoryWorkspace to ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, in-memory

I was trying to see if there was a way to visualize the data I am creating and placing in_memory and the [help page mentions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm) what the reference is named, but it doesn't at all instruct how to actually reference.

Most literature online talks about interacting with it in ArcPy, but I'm trying to specifically target it in ArcMap or ArcCatalog.

Comment: Make sure you're working in ArcMap if you want to "visual in_memory" items. ArcCatalog will only work if you persist something to disk. @BERA has provided some good code that works directly with the MAP in ArcMap.

Answer (score 1):

You can [list](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) all features in the in_memory workspace and add them to the map using [AddLayer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/addlayer.htm):

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

arcpy.env.workspace = r'in_memory'
for lyr in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(lyr)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
```

Or specify the name of a single feature:

```
...
lyr = 'NameOfFeature'
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(lyr)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
```

But this might not be what you are asking for?